# why when i put a proper value in semester variable my program crashes? C

Tags: c

```
struct student{
    char *number;
    char *name;
    int semester;
    float *grades;
};

typedef struct student RECORD;

void read_record(RECORD *p);
void print_record(RECORD x);
void init_record(RECORD *p);
void free_record(RECORD x);

main()
{
    int N;
    printf("Please enter the number of students that you want to insert: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);

    RECORD array[N];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        init_record(&array[i]);
```

at this point, when i put the semester value from the keyboard my program crashes

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("Number %d student: \n",i+1);
    read_record(&array[i]);     
}


for (i=0; i<N; i++)
print_record(array[i]);


    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        free_record(array[i]);
    }   
}
```

I tried to remove any unnecessary code but I left the most important parts so any false part would be easier to be seen

```
void read_record(RECORD *p)
{
        int i;

    printf("Please give the name: ");
    scanf("%s", p->name);

    printf("Please give AM number: ");
    scanf("%s", p->number);

    printf("Please give semester: ");
    scanf("%d",p->semester);

    printf("Please give grades: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    scanf("%f", &(p->grades[i]));
}
```

After this piece of code I have the `init_record` function that includes mallocs for struct's arrays

```
void init_record(RECORD *p)
{

    p->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    if (!p->name)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(0);
    }

    p->number = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    if (!p->number)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(0);
    }

    p->grades = malloc(sizeof(float)*5);
    if (!p->grades)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: scanf() and the like, note well, myFunc(arg) cannot modify 'arg'.  If you want a function to modify somethiing, you have to either return it or pass its address as an argument.

Comment: ...as, for some reason, you did with 'scanf("%f", &(p->grades[i]));' ...

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show us the `init_record` function

Comment: I put 'init_record'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've allocated the memory for the struct members

```
printf("Please give semester: ");
scanf("%d",p->semester);
```

is the problem, as `p->semester` is an `int`. `%d` expects a pointer to `int`, you are passing an uninitialized
integer value as a pointer to `scanf`.

The correct call would be

```
scanf("%d", &p->semester);
```

Usually once uses `malloc` because one need objects that live outside the scope
of function, for example with linked lists, trees, etc. But also when you need
an array whose dimension is not known on compiler time.

Your `init_record` seems to me pointless, because you know the size of the
arrays and they are even small, you could easily change your struct to

```
struct student {
    char number[6];
    char name[40];
    int semester;
    float grades[5];
};
```

and then you wouldn't need to do the `malloc` calls.

Also, you would need to do the `scanf` like this:

int c;

```
scanf("%39s", p->name);
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // clearing the buffer

scanf("%5s", p->number);
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // clearing the buffer

...
```

to prevent buffer overflows if the user enters a name/number that are too large
for the buffer.

---

**edit**

> *OP asked in the comments*
>
> One last thing: I wanted to replace scanf with `gets` in the case of name, because I want a name and a surname to be saved as one piece(including space). But when I replaced scanf, I got this error: request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union. I searched over here for a similar problem but I didn't find any solution. Can you suggest one?

Don't use `gets`, this is a dangerous function because it doesn't take the
size of the array into account and if the entered text is larger than the buffer
size, it will overflow and cause a lot of damage. The error message is due to a
syntax error, as you don't show the code, I cannot say what you did wrong.
However, if you take my advice, you won't have this error.

In general I advice not to use `scanf` to read from the user, because `scanf`
was not designed to do so. Specially when you want to read strings that have
empty spaces, it's better to read the whole line with `fgets` and
parse the line later using other functions like `strchr`, `strstr`, `strtok`,
`sscanf`, `strtol`, etc. Which function to use depends on what you are trying to
read from the user. In this case where you are reading strings, `fgets` would
give better results. So I'd change your whole reading process to this:

```
int read_record(RECORD *p)
{
    char line[1024];

    printf("Please give the name: ");
    if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read name\n");
        return 0; // error
    }

    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // removing newline
    strncpy(p->name, line, sizeof p->name);
    p->name[sizeof(p->name) - 1] = 0; // making sure to get a valid string

    printf("Please give AM number: ");
    if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read AM number\n");
        return 0;
    }

    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // removing newline
    strncpy(p->number, line, sizeof p->name);
    p->name[sizeof(p->number) - 1] = 0; // making sure to get a valid string

    // this is ok, this can stay like this
    printf("Please give semester: ");
    scanf("%d", &p->semester);

    printf("Please give grades: ");
    if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read grades\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(sscanf(line, "%f %f %f %f %f",
                p->grades, p->grades + 1, p->grades + 2, p->grades + 3,
                p->grades + 4) != 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read 5 grades\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1; // success
}
```

I know that it is much more code that you have before, but this code is more
robust, it handles cases where the user did input the wrong format, your code
can react to that, print error messages, retry the user input, whatever. With
your the error manifest themselves when the data printed on screen or a file is
strange.

Note how I copied the string:

```
strncpy(p->name, line, sizeof p->name);
p->name[sizeof(p->name) - 1] = 0; // making sure to get a valid string
```

Here I assuming that you've changed the struct to hold arrays like I said in the
first part of the answer. If you didn't change that and you are still using the
old way by `malloc`ing with a hardcoded fixed size, you will have to use the
hardcoded fixed size here as well:

```
strncpy(p->name, line, 40);
p->name[39] = 0; // making sure to get a valid string
```

And you see why I prefer when the struct has the array, because with `sizeof` I
can get the size regardless of the dimension.

The other thing to notice here is that I used `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.
`strcpy` suffers from the same problems as `gets`, it doesn't take the size of
the destination buffer into consideration and if the source string is larger
than the destination buffer, it will overflow the buffer.

`strncpy` works like `strcpy` except that you pass how many bytes there is
available for the destination buffer. If the source is larger than that number,
then `strncpy` will **not** writing bytes in the destination, thus preventing a
buffer overflow. Of course if the `'\0'`-terminating byte is not among the
copied bytes, it won't be written in the destination buffer. `p->name[39] = 0;`
just makes sure that the string is `'\0'`-terminated, no matter how long the
source was.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. One last thing: I wanted to replace scanf with gets in the case of name, because I want a name and a surname to be saved as one piece(including space). But when I replaced scanf, I got this error: request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union. I searched over here for a similar problem but I didn't find any solution. Can you suggest one?

Comment: Thank you again, sir. I totally forgot about fgets. I' ll fix my code with your suggestions.

Comment: The Queen hasn't give me knighthood yet and probably never will, so please don't call me sir :)

Comment: I still get an anomaly running the program. Is it allowed to post a screenshot of the console or should I type the output?

Comment: Edit your question and make copy&paste of code and outputs. Screenshots are bad, because you cannot copy&paste to reproduce the errors, that's why we don't like pictures of code/input/output. Make and add the new code, don't replace the old one, otherwise the answer doesn't fit anymore to the question and people might vote to close the question.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. Again thanks for the tips. I'm new user and I'm trying to fit in the place here.

Comment: Ok, that's great. What was your problem?